# Convert a function from Javascript to JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function combo(){
  if(i % 2 !=0) {       
    document.getElementById("list").style.visibility="visible";
    i=i+1;
    console.log(i);
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("list").style.visibility="hidden";
    i=i+1;
  }
}
```

Can I do this?

> var list = $("list").style.visibility="visible";

instead of:

> document.getElementById("list").style.visibility="visible";

Comment: Read http://api.jquery.com/css/ to get an ID in jquery it's `$('#idHere')` a little research goes a long way, specially when you are asking questions on here

Comment: You might want to show some effort yourself by googling `jQuery visibility`

Comment: `$('#list').css("visibility", "hidden")`

Comment: Do you really want to change specifically "visibility"?  or do you just want:  `function combo() { $("#list").toggle(); }` and be done with it?

Comment: @freedomn-m I just want to change it into JQuery. I have also some functions besides that. Thank you :)

Comment: "just change it into jquery" - well that's what I've provided for you.  Like I say, depends on whether you really want to affect visibility or just want the thing hidden.  Look at what you're trying to achieve rather than how you're trying to do it.

Comment: `document.getElementById("list")` in jquery = `$("#list").get(0)`

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use css with jQuery is:

```
$('#list').css({visibility:'visible'});
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/css/